# Automatic SE link renaming sometimes fails

Tags: bug

Sometimes automatic SE link renaming fail to work properly, e.g.:

[image]

It also impacts the post itself, not just the preview:

[image]

Links in the image:

- [How can I connect my CDJ / DJM 2000 Nexus with Traktor?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/15664/2589)
- [How can configure Rekorbox so that it records the computed BPM in the MP3 ID3's BPM field?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/27916/6753)
- [Can I force Traktor to use more than one CPU when analyzing tracks?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/16242/2589)

Links to post: https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/173/6753

And sometimes, it works fine. I use Google Chrome 33 on Windows 7.

Comment: It's better to provide the links in a text format.

Comment: @AvinashRaj sure, added.

Comment: Guess you are talking about the preview, given that both the post here  and on meta.sd are showing the links just fine?

Comment: @Oded It also impacts the post itself, not just the preview (image added in question).

Comment: @TimStone Thanks, but it says "Links to questions on the same site (or the master site / sub site, i.e. from SO to facebook.SO and the other way around) are unlimited. Links to other sites are limited to 5 linked-to sites". Shouldn't my 3 limits be below the limit?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yes, but per part 3, section b and e: "On all meta sites, links to the corresponding main site work, and vice versa. ... Anything else does not work."

Comment: @TimStone Thanks, this explains. Wicked rules!